# /home/NAME/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4773

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having problem with my wordpress website. I have disabled all the plugin. But an error is showing on wp-admin/ page.

> Notice: map_meta_cap was called incorrectly. The post type
>   scheduled-action is not registered, so it may not be reliable to check
>   the capability "read_post" against a post of that type. Please see
>   Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added
>   in version 4.4.0.) in /home/NAME/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 4773

Does any one know how do i solve this problem?

Comment: try shifting themes

Comment: @charan kumar is there no other way to solve this problem?

Comment: you need to debug from your end, you need to findout where the map_meta_cap is loading from.

Comment: Have you changed your user roles in any way because map_meta_cap relates to user roles https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/map_meta_cap/